# Force background image of div to be same as set background image for large screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Confusing question but let me explain.

I have an automatically placed background image that only appears on a larger screen.

This code below is embedded into the page with the website software I'm using:

```
<style>
 #quicksearch-section {
   background: url('https://t3.realgeeks.media/thumbnail/vEGNvOFFM5RYkOVTlPpzUhtrdUA=/fit-in/0x550/https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/neighborhoodhomevalue.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover
 }
</style>
```

On a smaller screen, it won't allow me to do a "display:inherit" to bring up this image, even with an important tag — because the global CSS stylesheet which I can't delete sets the background image to "background: #f2f2f2 !important".

Is there a way to bring in the code above and use that background image with jquery/js? The code remains on the page no matter the screen size, so it must be possible. I will have a ton of pages that need this resolved, so I can't do a one time fix with that specific image above.

Comment: can you recreate your problem using https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Hmm not really. Take a look at this page. The desktop background image I want to make the mobile background image automatically: [link](https://www.bothellhomes.com/bothell/urbane-village/)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMQk5.png have a look, I think you desktop image is already set as background image in mobile view. https://t3.realgeeks.media/thumbnail/vEGNvOFFM5RYkOVTlPpzUhtrdUA=/fit-in/0x550/https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/neighborhoodhomevalue.jpg

Comment: No did you see that link on desktop? The background is different. I set that mobile image permanently as a temporary solution. See that link, I want to be able to dynamically make the mobile #quicksearch-section the same background image as desktop.

Comment: Write JS/jQuery to find the rogue global CSS tag and `.remove()` it, e.g. `$('head > style').remove()`.

Comment: Very confused your doubt. You can't just.. While you are unable to resolve this issue, take advantage and resolve some other problems on your site, such as some inputs that you created and put the same id. Another problem is that you placed a <style> tag outside the header

Comment: Isn't there a way to target and splice the <style> tag within the #quicksearch-section code? Yeah, I know it's ridiculous, but I have no access to it. It's from my web provider.